# conda install -c anaconda failed to install any packages via anaconda

Tags: linux, installation, anaconda

i found that my anaconda failed to intall any packages via anaconda. Can anyone help? 
(deformetrica) [qiningliu@localhost ~]$ conda install -c pytorch -c conda-forge -c anaconda -c aramislab deformetrica
Solving environment: failed

## >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 819, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 78, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 77, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 11, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 235, in install
    force_reinstall=context.force,
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 505, in solve_for_transaction
    force_remove, force_reinstall)
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 438, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned, force_remove)
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 179, in solve_final_state
    index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 560, in _prepare
    self.subdirs, prepared_specs)
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 215, in get_reduced_index
    new_records = query_all(spec)
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 184, in query_all
    return tuple(concat(future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)))
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 94, in query
    self.load()
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 148, in load
    _internal_state = self._load()
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 235, in _load
    _internal_state = self._process_raw_repodata_str(raw_repodata_str)
  File "/home/qiningliu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 348, in _process_raw_repodata_str
    info['fn'] = fn
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

`$ /home/qiningliu/anaconda3/bin/conda install -c pytorch -c conda-forge -c anaconda -c aramislab deformetrica`

Answer (score 0):

for your case isn't necesary to repeat the flag `-c`.
If you want to install several packages you just need to execute:

```
conda install -c pytorch conda-forge anaconda aramislab deformetrica
```

Comment: You are right, but i think that's not the main problem for me. I have also tried to install other packages via the channel anaconda, it doesn't work either

Comment: Oh, sorry it was a misunderstood, i found that there is an issue in github with some info/solutions [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7870#issuecomment-430909045)